# Tortoise Git Commit Lost

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I wonder if you could help me. I created a new branch on GitHub using the web interface. I checked out the master repository and switched to this branch and pulled, using tortoise git.

I made all my changes and went to commit them using tortoise git. On committing, I received the error that I had no branch selected to commit to. I switched to branch again and I committed other files. I noticed that the files I had originally committed, showed as committed via a green tick, but the commit message was missing from the log. The changes are absent from the remote repository, but still present on my hard drive.

I turned my computer off and went home, to fix the issue tomorrow, after all, the file changes were still on my hard drive. I asked a colleague for help with the issue and they performed a sync. The changes to my files on the missing commit are gone. There wasn't a warning that we would be reverting changes. Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I switched my repository to temp. Looking through the reflog, my commit appeared - not the normal log. I rebased to this commit and was able to retrieve my changes - phew.

Comment: Can you share the steps you took? Screenshots / commands issued would be very helpful!